# Prove function monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

I would like to show the function $\bar{\gamma}\left(\alpha,\delta,\mu,N\right)$ decreases in $\delta$, where

$\bar{\gamma}\left(\alpha,\delta,\mu,N\right)\equiv\chi+\sqrt{\chi\left(\chi+\frac{2\alpha\delta\left(N\mu\left(2-\delta\mu\right)+\alpha\left(N\left(1-\delta\mu\right)-1\right)\right)+\mu\left(4-\delta^2\mu^2\right)N}{\alpha^2\delta^2\mu\left(N+1\right)}\right)}$,
where $\chi=\frac{\delta\mu\left(N+1\right)}{2\left(N-1+\delta\mu\right)}$, 
$N>2$, $\alpha, \mu, \delta>0$, $\alpha\delta<1$, $\mu\delta<1$.

Comment: First, I would try graphing the function (with generic values of the other variables) to verify the claim that it is decreasing. Then, you might try taking the derivative and showing it's negative. Maybe complete the square?  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Graphing the function indeed points towards it being decreasing. The derivative is again very complicated. I can show that $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial \bar{\gamma}}{\partial \delta} = -\infty$ and $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\partial \bar{\gamma}}{\partial \delta} = 0$.

This is, as you might have guessed, a root of a quadratic equation. Can I prove the monotonicity of the root by using the original equation?

Comment: If it's the root of a quadratic equation, can you use implicit differentiation to find $\frac{\partial \bar\gamma}{\partial \delta}$ in terms of $\bar \gamma$?

Comment: That's exactly what I was on now. Say the implicit function is $f\left(\bar{\gamma},\delta\right)=0$, then I would need to show: $\frac{\partial \bar{\gamma}}{\partial \delta}=-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{\gamma}}\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \delta}<0$, right? I am not sure where the fact the equation has two roots come into place though. I can show $-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{\gamma}}\right)^{-1}>0$ so far.